# How to go about attaching a rotary table to a mounted bearing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm new to all of this and am working on a project with someone. They mentioned using this kind of a rotary table, [Velmex - Motorized Rotary Tables](https://www.velmex.com/Products/Rotary_Tables/Motorized-Rotary-Tables.html):

[image: Motorized Rotary Tables]

and mounting it on a flat horizontal surface using a mounted bearing of some kind - like this but larger, [Pillow Block Bearing, Number of Bolts: 2, Ball Bearing Type, 7/8" Bore Dia.](https://www.grainger.com/product/36UZ04?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!50916755157!!!g!109230485397!&ef_id=Wh_ziQAAAsT13BME:20180613235028:s):

[image: Pillow Block Bearing]

The descriptions that I'm reading are saying that the rotary table comes with bearing of its own? So I'm confused if this is something that's possible. I'm going to look through some more diagrams of the rotary table and see if I can see how a shaft would go through

You don't need to tell me how it can be done, just if it is something that's possible because my other idea was using an L-shaped clamp, something like this, [Large L Shaped Clamp with Extra Holes for Mounting](https://hacktronics.co.in/mechanical-parts/large-l-shaped-clamp-with-extra-holes-for-mounting):

[image: Large L Shaped Clamp with Extra Holes for Mounting]

Comment: Adding images and tidying the links makes your post much more readable :-)

Answer (score 3):

On the [product page](https://www.velmex.com/Products/Rotary_Tables/Motorized-Rotary-Tables.html) you linked, there is a drawing that shows how the rotary table should be mounted. On the right side of the drawing you can see the mounting holes. The annotation also tells you that you can mount either from the top or from the bottom and which bolts you should use.

[image: Drawing of rotary table]

There does not seem to be any need to devise some kind of bearing or other mechanism to mount that rotary table to a flat and horizontal surface.